Buttons not working in data table | Tailwick | Flask | Jquery
I am using the datatable from the tailwick library (https://themesdesign.in/tailwick/html/tables-datatable.html). But the problem is that the buttons on the 2nd page aren't working at all. I have gone thorugh tens of forum posts but none of them solves my problem (Probably coz i didnt developed the webpage and the web page isn't defining a datatable explicitly). So, can anyone please help me?
Here's the code for table:
<table class="w-full whitespace-nowrap" id="basic_tables">
                    <thead class="ltr:text-left rtl:text-right bg-slate-100 text-slate-500 dark:text-zink-200 dark:bg-zink-600">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">NO</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">CAMPAIGN ID</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">CAMPAIGN_NAME</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">CLIENT_ID</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">COMPANY</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">CAMPAIGN_LP</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">TARGET_AUDIENCE</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">TESTED_INTERNALLY</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">SALES_PROCESS</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">CPL_RANGE</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">EXTRA_COMMENTS</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">STATUS</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">PAID</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">FORM_FIELDS</th>
                            <th class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 font-semibold border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="dataTable">
                        {% if cam != [] %}
                            {% for item in cam %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">{{ "%02d"|format(loop.index) }}</td>
                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">#CA{{ item['id'] + 1000 }}</td>
                                    {% for key, value in item.items() %}
                                            {% if key == 'client_id' %}
                                                <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">#CL{{ value + 1000 }}</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if key != 'id' and key != 'status' and key != 'tested_internally' and key != 'paid' and key != 'cpl_range' and key!= 'client_id' %}
                                                {% if value is none %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500"></td>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">{{ value }}</td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if key == 'cpl_range' %}
                                                <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">€{{ value }}</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if key == 'tested_internally' or key == 'paid' %}
                                                {% if value == 'true' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500" id="yes" style="color : transparent; font-size: 0px;"><svg style="margin-left: 30%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#4ade80" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" data-lucide="check" class="lucide lucide-check size-4"><path d="M20 6 9 17l-5-5"></path></svg>yes</td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'false' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500" id="no" style="color : transparent; font-size: 0px;"><svg style="margin-left: 30%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#ef4444" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" data-lucide="x" class="lucide lucide-x size-4 text-red-500"><path d="M18 6 6 18"></path><path d="m6 6 12 12"></path></svg>no</td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if key == 'status' %}
                                                {% if value == '' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500"></td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'Preparing Test' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                                        <span class="delivery_status px-2.5 py-0.5 text-xs inline-block font-medium rounded border bg-green-100 border-green-200 text-green-500 dark:bg-green-500/20 dark:border-green-500/20">Preparing Test</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'Test Live' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                                        <span class="delivery_status px-2.5 py-0.5 text-xs inline-block font-medium rounded border bg-yellow-100 border-yellow-200 text-yellow-500 dark:bg-yellow-500/20 dark:border-yellow-500/20">Test Live</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'Analizing' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                                        <span class="delivery_status px-2.5 py-0.5 text-xs inline-block font-medium rounded border bg-purple-100 border-purple-200 text-purple-500 dark:bg-purple-500/20 dark:border-purple-500/20">Analizing</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'Paused' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                                        <span class="px-2.5 py-0.5 inline-block text-xs font-medium rounded border bg-red-100 border-transparent text-red-500 dark:bg-red-500/20 dark:border-transparent">Paused</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'Proposal' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                                        <span class="px-2.5 py-0.5 inline-block text-xs font-medium rounded border bg-orange-100 border-transparent text-orange-500 dark:bg-orange-500/20 dark:border-transparent">Proposal</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if value == 'Campaign Live' %}
                                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                                        <span class="px-2.5 py-0.5 inline-block text-xs font-medium rounded border bg-cyan-100 border-transparent text-cyan-500 dark:bg-cyan-500/20 dark:border-transparent">Campaign Live</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    <td class="px-3.5 py-2.5 first:pl-5 last:pr-5 border-y border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-500">
                                        <div class="relative dropdown">

<-- This is not working -->

                                            <button id="estimateAction1" class="flex items-center justify-center size-[30px] dropdown-toggle p-0 text-slate-500 btn bg-slate-100 hover:text-white hover:bg-slate-600 focus:text-white focus:bg-slate-600 focus:ring focus:ring-slate-100 active:text-white active:bg-slate-600 active:ring active:ring-slate-100 dark:bg-slate-500/20 dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:bg-slate-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:bg-slate-500 dark:focus:text-white dark:active:bg-slate-500 dark:active:text-white dark:ring-slate-400/20"
                                                onclick="">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" data-lucide="more-horizontal" class="lucide lucide-more-horizontal size-3">
                                                    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                                                    <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                                                    <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                                                </svg>
                                            </button>
                                            <ul id="dropdownMenu" class="absolute z-50 py-2 mt-1 ltr:text-left rtl:text-right list-none bg-white rounded-md shadow-md dropdown-menu min-w-[10rem] dark:bg-zink-600 hidden" aria-labelledby="estimateAction1" data-popper-placement="bottom-end" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px 0px auto auto; margin: 0px; transform: translate(-17px, 26px);">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a data-modal-target="editCampaign" class="block px-4 py-1.5 text-base transition-all duration-200 ease-linear text-slate-600 dropdown-item hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-500 focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-500 dark:text-zink-100 dark:hover:bg-zink-500 dark:hover:text-zink-200 dark:focus:bg-zink-500 dark:focus:text-zink-200 edit-button" data-campaign-id="{{ item.id }}">
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" data-lucide="file-edit" class="lucide lucide-file-edit inline-block size-3 ltr:mr-1 rtl:ml-1">
                                                            <path d="M4 13.5V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8.5L20 7.5V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-5.5"></path>
                                                            <polyline points="14 2 14 8 20 8"></polyline>
                                                            <path d="M10.42 12.61a2.1 2.1 0 1 1 2.97 2.97L7.95 21 4 22l.99-3.95 5.43-5.44Z"></path>
                                                        </svg> 
                                                        <span class="align-middle">Edit</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a data-modal-target="deleteModal" class="block px-4 py-1.5 text-base transition-all duration-200 ease-linear text-slate-600 dropdown-item hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-500 focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-500 dark:text-zink-100 dark:hover:bg-zink-500 dark:hover:text-zink-200 dark:focus:bg-zink-500 dark:focus:text-zink-200" href="javascript:showDeleteConfirmation({{ item.id }})">
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" data-lucide="trash-2" class="lucide lucide-trash-2 inline-block size-3 ltr:mr-1 rtl:ml-1">
                                                            <path d="M3 6h18"></path>
                                                            <path d="M19 6v14c0 1-1 2-2 2H7c-1 0-2-1-2-2V6"></path>
                                                            <path d="M8 6V4c0-1 1-2 2-2h4c1 0 2 1 2 2v2"></path>
                                                            <line x1="10" x2="10" y1="11" y2="17"></line>
                                                            <line x1="14" x2="14" y1="11" y2="17"></line>
                                                        </svg> 
                                                        <span class="align-middle">Delete</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
.... Some lines later ........
<script src="{{url_for('static' ,filename='js/datatables/jquery-3.7.0.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static' ,filename='js/datatables/data-tables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static' ,filename='js/datatables/data-tables.tailwindcss.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static' ,filename='js/datatables/datatables.init.js')}}"></script>

Can anyone please tell me, how can I fix this error?

I went through different forum posts but none of them worked for me (as most of the guys werent using a library that manages these triggers).
I also tried writing my adding my own function and even listner for opening the dropdown and editing but in vain!


I am desperately looking for an answer
